# How to increase the vehicle density in Veins-lte during simulation

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins

I would like to increase the number of vehicles per area i.e vehicle density. In case of veins; the number of vehilces as well as speed can be increased or decreased via erlagen.rou.xml. I tried to change the number of vehicles from heterogeneous.rou.xml, but i faced some errors like :
     Error in module (HeterogeneousToLTE) scenario.node[1].heterogeneousToLTE (id=89) at event #192976, t=20.6: IPvXAddressResolver: module `node[21]' not found

How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If anybody has any idea or hints on how to increase the number of vehicles, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the number of vehicles you have to generate/build a new scenario for **SUMO**. **Veins LTE** only covers the network simulation part.

The error you posted has a different reason: You are trying to send a message to a node that does not yet exist. To fix this, you have to change either the provided `SimpleApp.cc`, or even better, write your own application.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do as your suggestion.